# Retrieve interpolated value from look up table

Tags: matlab, interpolation, lookup-tables

I have a function in which a look up table is created. LUT has some random x points and corresponding Y values. Now I have another function which uses a loop to find exact X point say xq. In each loop I also need to find the corresponding Y value (yq) by **passing only the current Xq** to another function which should **interpolate** and obtain Yq value in case Xq value is not found in the LUT and is within limit. But I find that I have to pass the x and Y array used in LUT as well as current xq point each time in my loop if I use **interp1**. Is there any other means to get Yq value **without passing the entire x and y arrays**?
I have given the structure of the code below.

```
func to create LUT
        x = [1.8558;2.5549;3.4438;4.433;5.5271;6.5236;7.4795;8.4345;9.232;9.8256;10.4205;10.9303;11.3257;11.8103];
        y = [0.0433;0.0598;0.0672;0.0749;0.0945;0.0991;0.0858;0.0857;0.0894;0.0788;0.0838;0.0815;0.0866;0.0971];

 main func

    for i = 1:1:1000
        expression for xq ;
        call func to find yq from LUT by passing only xq ;
        do something using xq and yq ;
    end
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to retrieve an interpolated value from `y` without knowing where the `Xq`-value is in `x`?

Comment: You should not be concerned passing the entire x and y arrays as parameters to your function. As long as you don't modify array values, Matlab doesn't copy the array content (the array is passed by reference).